# how to create and append date to xml file through ajax

Tags: ajax, jquery

Some part of chat app is over, well Im able to read from an xml file using Ajax but how do i write to an xml file through Ajax? Does Ajax support file modes? I want to create xml file if it does not exist and append some data to it if it exists.

I have used Post method but Im unable to solve it Please someone let me know how to create and append data to an xml file through ajax.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ajax` is a technology used by client. So it is obviously not possible to edit file on server